# Why Java SimpleDateFormat().parse() is printing weird formate?

Tags: java, string, datetime, simpledateformat

My input is String formated as the following:

```
3/4/2010 10:40:01 AM
3/4/2010 10:38:31 AM
```

My code is:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
            try
            {
                Date today = dateFormat.parse(time);
                System.out.println("Date Time : " + today);

            }
            catch (ParseException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

the output is:

```
Sun Jan 03 10:38:31 AST 2010
Sun Jan 03 10:40:01 AST 2010
```

I'm not sure from where the day (Sun) came from? or (AST)? and why the date is wrong? I just wanted to keep the same format of the original **String** date and make it into a **Date** object.

*I'm using Netbeans 6.8 Mac version.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print the date in the original format, use the format method:

```
System.out.println("Date Time : "+ dateFormat.format(today));
```

the "weird" format comes from Date's toString implementation, the javadoc says:



**Converts this Date object to a String of the form:**

dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy

```
"I just wanted to keep the same format of the original String date and make it into a Date object."
```

The Date Object is intended to represent a specific instant in time, you can't keep the format of the original string into it, that's why we have the DateFormat Class.

Comment: @MAK, the Date Object contains no "format", you should not print it if you're looking to formated output

Answer (score 7):

Should be MM, not mm.  The lowercase mm is for minutes, not months.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
```

Answer (score 4):

`MM`, not `mm` for months. You are using `mm` twice - and logically, it's the same things - minutes.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple. You have displayed the Date.toString() value of today and not the intended dateFormat version. what you require is:

```
System.out.println("Date Time : " + dateFormat.format(today) );
```

Comment: but I need the String to be Date object!

Comment: The Date object can be passed as a parameter to other methods if that is what you require. To display the date in the format you chose requires you to use it as an argument to the format method of the dateFormat instance.

Answer (score 1):

Printing the Date out using System.out.println() results in the [toString()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) method being called on the Date object.

The format string used in toString() is what is causing the Day of the week and the timezone to appear in the output.

This is apart from the parsing mistake pointed out by Duffy.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent that?